# No templates for condition page.php Elementor

Tags: theme-development, page-template

I am building a WordPress theme and I want it to support the Elementor theme. But I get this error in Elementor Debugging mode.

`No Template for condition > theme name -page.php`

What could be the cause?

This my page.php

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_title( );
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Noting here that the answer given only works for the original author, and that questions about Elementor/3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. This should have been asked in an Elementor community or their official support routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem and it was nothing related to the template files.

I had dequeue jquery and instead re-enqueued my custom `jquery` as `Jquery` instead of `jquery` which is used by Elementor and that was the cause of the issue.

This is how my code was.

```
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('Jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/vendor/jquery/jquery.js', false, '3.4.1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('Jquery');
```

this I was my fix

```
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/vendor/jquery/jquery.js', false, '3.4.1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Comment: Which file should edit to solve this problem

Comment: Which file to edit depends on which theme you are using, lots of themes do this and they have different files and locations. Even a plugin can do this! So you need to find the place it's in on your server, I or Isakiye can't tell you that without searching your specific individual unique server. In this case Isakiye knew where it was because they were the one who wrote it

Comment: of course, deleting all 4 lines and not dequeing jQuery is better

Comment: have done it on the theme functions.php file. Kindly confirm